# Significance of 'Timing stopped at:' in R studio

Tags: r, rstudio

I was trying to run a code completely in R studio, and it was taking time. After 10 hours I interrupted and it is showing **Timing stopped at: 1.43 0.69 1.644e+04** ,
What is the meaning of this line? how I can understand how much the task completed before interruption ?

Comment: Good question. 1.644e+04 seconds is 4.5 hours, which is plausible enough for how much cpu time might be consumed in 10 hours, though I am just guessing.

Comment: The three numbers are the user, system, and elapsed time (see `?proc.time`). The final number is the total elapsed time in seconds, as the comment above notes that's ~4.5 hours.

Comment: Without knowing anything about the task, "how I can understand how much the task completed before interruption ?" is impossible to answer. Maybe it was 99.99% done and you threw in the towel one second too soon. Maybe you were trying to do something intractable like factor a large semiprime and it would have taken centuries. More likely than not, you were somewhere in between.